# Percentage of group total

Tags: sql, group-by, percentage, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to add a new column which would calculate the percentage total of each pack type for that week.

The code below results in the following.

[image]

So I would like the new column to display the percentage of the total number of hectoliters for that specific week.

Code:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

SELECT 

DATEPART (wk, t0.U_ORC_BE_ProdDate) AS [Week Produced],
--Display week number of date produced
(
CASE 
    WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%Cans%' 
        THEN 'Cans'
    WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%Bottles%'
        THEN 'Bottles'
    WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%Key Keg%'
        THEN 'Key Keg'
    WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%SS Keg%'
        THEN 'SS Keg'
    WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%E-Keg%'
        Then 'SS Keg'
END
)AS [Pack Type],
--Collate item types to pack types
sum(t5.U_ORC_BE_HECTOLITER * t0.CmpltQty) AS [Total Hectoliters]
--Calculate total HL in the order


FROM OWOR T0  
INNER JOIN OITT T1 ON T0.ItemCode = T1.Code 
INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.Code = T2.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN [@ORC_BE_PACK_TYPE] t5 ON t5.Code = t2.U_ORC_BE_PACK_TYPE
LEFT JOIN [@ORC_BE_STYLE_H] t6 ON t6.Code= t2.U_ORC_BE_ShortCode

WHERE   
   (t5.U_ORC_BE_HECTOLITER * t0.CmpltQty) != 0 
AND U_ORC_BE_ProcessType = 'Packaging'
AND 
    (
     T0.[U_ORC_BE_ProdDate] >=  dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 13, 0)
     AND T0.[U_ORC_BE_ProdDate] < dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0)
    ) 
--For previous 12 weeks

GROUP BY datepart(wk, t0.U_ORC_BE_ProdDate), 

     t0.U_Operator,
    (
    CASE 
        WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%Cans%' 
            THEN 'Cans'
        WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%Bottles%'
            THEN 'Bottles'
        WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%Key Keg%'
            THEN 'Key Keg'
        WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%SS Keg%'
            THEN 'SS Keg'
        WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%E-Keg%'
            Then 'SS Keg'
    END
    )

ORDER BY datepart (wk, t0.U_ORC_BE_ProdDate) ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUM() OVER() to aggregate the full amount for each calendar unit and do the percentage calculation with that.

```
 SELECT
      d.*
    , ([Total Hectoliters] * 100.0) / SUM([Total Hectoliters]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Week Produced]) [Weekly Pct]
FROM (
      SELECT
            DATEPART(wk, t0.U_ORC_BE_ProdDate)        AS [Week Produced]
            --Display week number of date produced
          , (
            CASE
                  WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%Cans%' THEN 'Cans'
                  WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%Bottles%' THEN 'Bottles'
                  WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%Key Keg%' THEN 'Key Keg'
                  WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%SS Keg%' THEN 'SS Keg'
                  WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%E-Keg%' THEN 'SS Keg'
            END
            )                                         AS [Pack Type]
            --Collate item types to pack types
          , SUM(t5.U_ORC_BE_HECTOLITER * t0.CmpltQty) AS [Total Hectoliters]
      --Calculate total HL in the order
      FROM OWOR T0
            INNER JOIN OITT T1 ON T0.ItemCode = T1.Code
            INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.Code = T2.ItemCode
            INNER JOIN [@ORC_BE_PACK_TYPE] t5 ON t5.Code = t2.U_ORC_BE_PACK_TYPE
            LEFT JOIN [@ORC_BE_STYLE_H] t6 ON t6.Code = t2.U_ORC_BE_ShortCode
      WHERE (t5.U_ORC_BE_HECTOLITER * t0.CmpltQty) <> 0
            AND U_ORC_BE_ProcessType = 'Packaging'
            --For previous 12 weeks
            AND (T0.[U_ORC_BE_ProdDate] >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()) - 13, 0)
            AND T0.[U_ORC_BE_ProdDate] < DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
            )
      GROUP BY
            DATEPART(wk, t0.U_ORC_BE_ProdDate)
          , t0.U_Operator
          , (
            CASE
                  WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%Cans%' THEN 'Cans'
                  WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%Bottles%' THEN 'Bottles'
                  WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%Key Keg%' THEN 'Key Keg'
                  WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%SS Keg%' THEN 'SS Keg'
                  WHEN t5.U_ORC_BE_NAME LIKE '%E-Keg%' THEN 'SS Keg'
            END
            )
) AS d
ORDER BY
      [Week Produced] ASC
```

By the way because your where clause insists that alias t5 meets some conditions there is no point in using a left join on t5. That is, because every row has to meet those conditions then a NULL result from t5 is ignored, therefore an outer join is irrelevant for that table.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your table screenshot only I wrote this query without going much deep into the query you provided. Not sure this is the final outcome you wanted. If not, you may need to merge this with your query :)

```
SELECT z.WeekProduced, z.PackType, z.packTotal, ( z.packTotal / z.WeekTotal ) as Percentage
FROM
((SELECT WeekProduced, PackType, SUM(Totalhectoliters) as packTotal
FROM GivenTable
GROUP BY WeekProduced, PackType )  AS x INNER JOIN            
(SELECT WeekProduced, SUM(Totalhectoliters) as WeekTotal
FROM GivenTable
GROUP BY WeekProduced ) AS y 
ON x.WeekProduced = y.WeekProduced ) AS z
```

Comment: Thanks, that's similar to what I was trying but I just couldn't quite wrap my head around it.